# C++: Serialize object on SIGUSR signal

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, signals

Let's assume that a program is bound to terminate before it runs its due course. The termination signal can be specified by the user (the program runs on a cluster that uses a MOAB scheduler).
Moreover, let's assume that a cooldown period can be added, i.e. a warning signal (`SIGUSR1`)  is sent `X` seconds/minutes prior to termination (`SIGKILL`),

How would one go about saving the memory state for checkpointing purposes?

I toyed around ideas invovling [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/) of the objects of interest + program state variables, i.e. something like

```
class Foo
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & x;
        ar & y;
    }
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Foo(){};
    Foo(int x_, int y_) :
        x(x_), y(y_)
    {}
};

void handler (const Foo & f)
{
  //serialize and dump FOO
  std::ofstream ofs("dump");
  {
      boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
      oa << f;
  }
  // exit
  exit(0);
}


int main ()
{

  Foo bar(1, 2);

  void (*sighandler)( /* ?*/ );
  sighandler = signal (SIGUSR, handler);

  //do stuff
}
```

I do not know how to pass `Foo` to the signal handler.
From what I gather, signal handling must be performed at a global scope, i.e. objects that must be saved cannot be properly scoped.
Thus, my solution would not work.

For the record, I looked into higher level options, such as [BLCR](https://ftg.lbl.gov/projects/CheckpointRestart/), but the problem is that I handle parallelization at a high level with [`gnu-parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html), such that BLCR saves the state of parallel, rather than the child processes.

Comment: Is you question how to hook into the signal handler, or how to serialize your data? You'll probably have to have some global reference to a piece of data that you want to serialize, so that you can find it from your handler.

Comment: @Steve I want to know how to hook it all with a signal handler. Serialization is easy thanks to boost! Sorry for the confused explanation.

Comment: Google has some answers. [Here's one.](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html)

Comment: As far as I know, neither `std::ofstream` nor Boost.Serialization provide the guarantee of being [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html), so using them to within the handling of an asynchronous signal may invoke undefined behavior.  However, there are ways to synchronously handle the signals.  Can you provide details on the program's threading?  Is there at least one thread that runs a loop where periodic checks could occur?

Comment: Thanks for the input. The program is single-threaded. It's a simulation that runs in a big while loop (hence the parallelization with gnu-parallel). So yes, checks can occur multiple time per second (or less, there's a branch that is visited ~once per minute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be quite a few intricate details involved to properly handle signals.  For example, when asynchronously handling a signal, one is limited to using [async-signal-safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html).  Calling any non-reentrant safe function may result in undefined behavior.

For this particular case, it may be worth using Boost.Asio's support for [signal handling](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/signals.html).  It handles all of the low-level details, allowing the user to control when the signal is handled without being limited to async-signal-safe functions.

```cpp
void handle_signal(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                   int signal_number)
{
  if (error) return;
  // signal occurred, can use non-reentrant functions to handle it.
}

...

// Register to handle SIGUSR1.
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGUSR1);

// Asynchronously wait for a signal to occur.
signals.async_wait(&handle_signal);

while (running)
{
  ...
  io_service.poll(); // Check it signal was received.
}
```

---

When handling signals, there are two categories of signals:

- *thread-directed* signals are signals that are bound for a specific thread.  These include certain signals, such as `SIGSEGV` and `SIGFPE`, that are generated when the given thread executes specific machine-language instructions.  Additionally, signals can be sent to specific threads via [`pthread_kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html).  Some literature refers to these signals as *synchronous* signals.
- *process-directed* signals are signals that are destined to a specific process.  The kernel will deliver the signal to any thread that does not have the signal blocked.  Some literature refers to these as *asynchronous* signals.

And handling a signal can be performed:

- asynchronous: the signal is handled at an arbitrary point of execution.  When a signal is delivered to a thread that has not blocked it, the thread will be interrupted and execute the associated signal handler that has been registered with [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).  As the thread is interrupted at an arbitrary point, the current context may be unknown, so only reentrant functions may be safely invoked.  For example, consider the case where a thread has acquired a mutex, is interrupted with a signal, then attempts to acquire the same mutex in the signal handler, resulting in a deadlock.  Even the signal handler itself may be interrupted by a signal.
- synchronous: the signal is blocked and explicitly handled at a known point.  Threads may choose to block signals.  When a thread-directed signal is sent to a thread that has blocked the signal or when a process-directed signal is received by a process wherein all threads have blocked the signal, the signal will be placed into a *pending* state.  Functions such as [`sigwait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) can be invoked to obtain information about pending signals.  As an application explicitly makes a call to obtain signal information rather than being interrupted, the current context is known, so non-reentrant functions may be invoked.

When synchronously handling process-directed signals, such as those sent from the [`kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command, it is important to make sure all threads have blocked the signal.  Otherwise, the signal may be asynchronously handled by another thread.  This is often accomplished by using a signal mask to set blocked and ignored signals in the main thread, as child threads will inherit their parent's thread mask upon creation.  However, this approach may not be guaranteed to work, as one may not have control over internal threads in third-party libraries.  There is a technique that eliminates the need to manage signal mask while still allowing signals to be handled in a synchronous manner known as the [self-pipe trick](https://www.google.com/?#q=self-pipe+trick).

The self-pipe trick will create an internal pipe to communicate signal information.  A fairly basic signal handler is registered with `sigaction()` that will asynchronously handle the signal by writing the received signal number to the pipe.  One can then read from the other end of the pipe to receive the signal information.  This technique is used by Boost.Asio.  Furthermore, as Boost.Asio uses a reactor and the internal pipe is non-blocking, one can asynchronously handle signal information without being in the context of an interruption.

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20b7a573ee00f9ef) a small application that handles `SIGUSR1` then gracefully exits:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// Mockup model.
class Foo {};

// Mockup serializer.
void store_state(Foo& foo)
{
  // ... serialize state with Boost.Serialization ...
  // ... persists state, perhaps to the filesystem or a
  //     message queue
  std::cout << "Storing state for object: " << &foo << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  bool running = true;
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << "Object is: " << &foo << std::endl;

  // Setup signal handling.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service);
  signals.add(SIGUSR1);
  signals.async_wait([&running, &foo](
      const boost::system::error_code& error,
      int signal_number) 
    {
      // On error, return early.
      if (error) return;
      std::cout << "Handling SIGUSR1: " 
                << std::boolalpha << (SIGUSR1 == signal_number)
                << std::noboolalpha << std::endl;

      // Set flag to allow graceful exit.
      running = false;

      // Store the state.
      store_state(foo);
    });

  // Main work loop.
  while (running)
  {
    std::cout << "Busy work" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

    io_service.poll(); // Handle signals.
  }
  std::cout << "Finish" << std::endl;
}
```

Execution and output:

```
./a.out &
PID=$!
sleep 2
kill -s SIGUSR1 $PID
Object is: 0x7fff8a1e620f
Busy work
Busy work
Busy work
Busy work
Handling SIGUSR1: true
Storing state for object: 0x7fff8a1e620f
Finish
```